# Python / Selenium - how do i stay signed in after calling a second driver.get()?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, get

I have this code to log into cbt nuggets and afterwards i want to go into my playlists and collect some URLs

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui



capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}  # chromedriver 75+

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={userdata_path}") #Path to your chrome profile

# options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
# options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors", "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection", "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", "disable-client-side-phishing-detection"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriver_path, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.cbtnuggets.com/login")
logs = driver.get_log("performance")

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

#wait=ui.WebDriverWait(driver,300)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#wait.until(page_is_loaded)

USERNAME = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
USERNAME.send_keys("johndoe@gmail.com")

PASSWORD = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input")
PASSWORD.send_keys("password")

Login_Button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/button")
Login_Button.click()

driver.get("https://www.cbtnuggets.com/learn/it-training/playlist/nrn:playlist:user:5fcf88f463ebba00155acb18/2?autostart=1")
```

it all works as expected, but when the last `driver.get()` executes, i get thrown back to the login page, but when i manually enter the second URL in the address bar it works as expected without having to log in again.
I dont know if this is a selenium issue, or if i am misunderstanding something about how HTTP Get works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to parse the login result? This might happen because the login request is not fully processed yet.

After `Login_Button.click()` you should check if the site is logged in successfully or not. You have many ways to check:

- If the site redirects: check for the title of the page
- If the site display a dialog: create a fluent wait to check for the dialog element to display
- If you don't even bother to check, just add `time.sleep(5)`. It's bad practice though.

After the check, now you use `driver.get` to go to the page you want.

Comment: oh, that was simple, just waiting 3 seconds did the job, thanks!